# Python: Parse anchor text using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse anchor texts(**example: Mercedes-Benz, 308, savivarčiai**) from one website.

Using: Python 3.4

```
<h2 class="title-list"><a href="http://auto.plius.lt/skelbimai/mercedes-benz-308-savivarciai-3876306.html" title="Mercedes-Benz, 308, savivarčiai" onclick="OpenNamedPopup('http://auto.plius.lt/skelbimai/mercedes-benz-308-savivarciai-3876306.html', 'A3876306'); return false;">Mercedes-Benz, 308, savivarčiai</a>&nbsp;</h2>
```

My code looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def autoplius():

    url = "http://auto.plius.lt/skelbimai/krovininis-transportas/sunkvezimiai?make_date_from=1989&make_date_to=1997&make_id=4169"
    r = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

    for link in soup.findAll('h2',{'class':'title-list'}):
        ahref = link.find('a')

        print(ahref.get('ahref'))


autoplius()
```

But return I get is bunch of lines with **none none none none none**..

And my second question is about encoding whenever I try to print something I get encoding problems

like this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x8d' in position 248: character maps to <undefined>
```

**How do I fix this?**

- NEW

Output for r.encoding:

```
ISO-8859-1
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I installed PyCharm and it works on PyCharm console. Problem was my windows terminal doesn't show Latin1 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let `requests.content` handle the encoding and get the text from the `a` tags:

```
def autoplius():    
    url = "http://auto.plius.lt/skelbimai/krovininis-transportas/sunkvezimiai?make_date_from=1989&make_date_to=1997&make_id=4169"
    r = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = r.content
    print(plain_text)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

    for link in soup.findAll('h2',{'class':'title-list'}):
        print(link.a.text)


Mercedes-Benz, 308, savivarčiai
Mercedes-Benz, 609, kietašoniai
Mercedes-Benz, 308, bortiniai
Mercedes-Benz, 609, Šaldytuvai
Mercedes-Benz, 609, Šaldytuvai
Mercedes-Benz, 1114, važiuoklės
Mercedes-Benz, 3344AK, savivarčiai
Mercedes-Benz, 814, važiuoklės
Mercedes-Benz, 308, Šaldytuvai
Mercedes-Benz, 609, dviguba kabina
Mercedes-Benz, 609, Šaldytuvai
Mercedes-Benz, HMF 1150, savivarčiai su kranu
Mercedes-Benz, sprinter 312, kietašoniai
Mercedes-Benz, 814, Šaldytuvai
Mercedes-Benz, Sprinter 208, bortiniai
Mercedes-Benz, SPRINTER 308D, bortiniai
Mercedes-Benz, Sprinter 212 TDi, bortiniai
Mercedes-Benz, 711 MAXI, kietašoniai
Mercedes-Benz, 814, bortiniai
Mercedes-Benz, 208, bortiniai
Citroen Grand C4 Picasso
```

Comment: I still get encoding error when I run your code:

'UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u010d' in position 27: character maps to <undefined>'

'import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def autoplus():
 url = "http://auto.plius.lt/skelbimai/krovininis-transportas/sunkvezimiai?make_date_from=1989&make_date_to=1997&make_id=4169"
 r = requests.get(url)
 plain_text = r.content
 soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
 for link in soup.findAll('h2',{'class':'title-list'}):
    print(link.a.text)

autoplus()'

Comment: Posted answer with info

Comment: Edited my main question.

Comment: ERROR: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u010d' in position 27: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Comment: windows is a pain in the ass! try `print(link.a.text.encode("utf-8").decode("ISO-8859-1"))`

Comment: Still Same shit.. 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x8d'

Comment: ah windoze! I will have a think and see if I can come up with anything else

Comment: Thank you! this is a big headache for me if you come with a solution I will have to buy you a beer :)

Comment: what happens if you try `.encode("iso-8859-1", "replace")`

Comment: It just replaces characters with question mark. b'Mercedes-Benz, 308, savivar?iai'

Comment: try `soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,from_encoding="ISO-8859-1")`, also what version of requests and bs4 are you using?

Comment: I found workaround. It apears that fault was my windows terminal that didn't show latin1 chars. I installed Pycharm and it works now

Comment: yep the windows terminal is a serious pain in the ass, pycharm is a brilliant ide, I have used it since day one.